# What's the relationship between homebrew and xcode command line tools？

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

Are they the same thing?

I was reading the "homebrew-php" github page, and it mentions about xcode and its command line tools. 
My understanding about homebrew is it is a package manager like npm, why does it have anything to do with xcode, which I think doesn't have much to do with PHP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't include a compiler and other tools that would duplicate Apple's development tools. Instead of that - it just asks for you to get the basic tools from Apple.

Xcode uses the same tools under the hood as homebrew - so you could satisfy this specific requirement either by installing the command line tools directly or via an Xcode install.

So, they aren't the same thing and you need both for the brew package manager to run.

Comment: So it is like homebrew needs something to run, and xcode happens to have it, which is part of the "command line tools", so instead of include this "something" in itself, homebrew just tells its user to install xcode's CLT? Is this understanding right?

Comment: Do you really mean retirement or is it just a Freudian slip and you wanted to write requirement ;-)

Comment: @shenkwen Exactly. Rather than packaging and installing the same or equivalent - the brew folks tell you to get "pre-req" from Apple.

Comment: @klanomath the latter, and L O L - it’s not a bad thing to retire?!